# How do you shift each row in pandas data frame by a specific value?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

If I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
 2  3   4  NaN NaN  NaN
 1 NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN
 5  6   7   2   3   NaN
 4  3  NaN NaN NaN  NaN
```

and an array for the number I would like to shift:
     array = [2, 4, 0, 3]

How do I iterate through each row to shift the columns by the number in my array to get something like this:

```
 NaN  NaN   2   3   4   NaN
 NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN 1   NaN
  5    6    7   2   3   NaN
 NaN  NaN  NaN  3   4   NaN
```

I was trying to do something like this but had no luck.

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(values)
 for rows in df.iterrows():
   df[rows] = df.shift[change_in_bins[rows]]
```

Comment: Is the last column always NaN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use for loop with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
for index,value in enumerate([2, 4, 0, 3]):
    df.loc[index,:] = df.loc[index,:].shift(value)

print(df)
     0    1    2    3    4   5
0  NaN  NaN  2.0  3.0  4.0 NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0 NaN
2  5.0  6.0  7.0  2.0  3.0 NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  4.0  3.0 NaN
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @TroyZaremba You are Welcome!